# mysql 5.7 json data type search array of hashes

Tags: mysql, json

Suppose I have json data type column named **data**, and this column contains array of hashes, so for example: `[{x:1, y:2}, {x:3, y:4},...]`

Now can I json search this array for specific value of some key? That is select rows which have a hash with value of `x` key equal to 5, is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I found a solution for it

SELECT * FROM table where JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$[*].x'), 'search_val' = 1"